# How can I convert a SASS file to a CSS file in an ANT task?

Tags: css, ant, sass

How can I convert a SASS file to a CSS file in an ANT task?  I want to use SASS with my java web application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to convert Sass to CSS is:

```
sass input.sass output.css
```

I'm not very familiar with Ant, but this works for me. This will compile the `*.sass` files in `sass-dir` and output the CSS files to `css-dir`.

```
<target name="sass">
  <property name="css-dest" location="css-dir"/>
  <delete dir="${css-dest}"/>
  <mkdir dir="${css-dest}"/>
  <apply executable="sass" dest="${css-dest}">
    <srcfile/>
    <targetfile/>
    <fileset dir="sass-dir" includes="*.sass"/>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.sass" to="*.css"/>
  </apply>
</target>
```